# python how to demodulate iq fm signal that was moved to 0 frequency

Tags: python, scipy, frequency-modulation, numpy

I am struggling with implementing FM demodulation for IQ samples that has 0 center frequency from RTL-SDR ...
I have found the following algorithm for FM demodulation, see [FM demodulation](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/18616/66279):

```
analytic_signal = scipy.signal.hilbert(vfo_channel_fm.real)
baseband = analytic_signal
demod_channel = np.angle(baseband[1::1] * np.conjugate(baseband[0:-1:1]))
demod_channel = (demod_channel * (sampling_freq/decimation_factor)) / (2 * np.pi)
```

where vfo_channel is just IQ signal shifted by SDR receiver to 0 frequency

This algorithms works, but it has some issue with base sinusoidal signal (I see my voice decoded on sinusoidal signal), see image bellow:
[image: Sinusoidal signal with demodulated voice]

As you can see, my voice has a base sinusoidal signal and also some big signal changed in the middle of the signal

Is there anything that I missed implementing FM demodulation ?
Maybe there are a better algorithm ?

Comment: "I have found" -- _where_ have you found?   You should _cite any references_, in this case by _editing your question_ with a link to the page you found, or a reference to the source material if it's in a printed book.

Comment: While you are editing your question, explain what the signals are.  In particular, `vfo_channel` implies the output of a local oscillator; this would not contain any information unless _you have done something with it_ -- in which case, you should say what that is.  I.e., "`vfo_channel` is a test signal that I made that contains ...".

Comment: @TimWescott I have found this algorithm here https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/18616/66279

Comment: @TimWescott vfo_channel is just IQ signal shifted to 0 center frequency, it was shifted by SDR receiver

Comment: This is Stackexchange, where we like the _entire question_ and _entire answers_ to be _in the question and answers_.  **Not** buried in the comments.  Could you please _edit your question_ with this information.

Comment: Already updated

Answer (score 1):

Your error lies in misinterpreting the source material.

This line is not something to stick in randomly.  It is given *in your reference* as a way to get an I/Q signal from a real-valued FM signal that is *not* centered on 0Hz.

```
analytic_signal = scipy.signal.hilbert(vfo_channel_fm.real)
```

You state that your signal `vfo_channel_fm` is *already* an I/Q signal.  In the following line of code, when you just the real part of it you're mangling the signal -- you're basically throwing away half of the information.  Presumably the reason that your output has that enormous glitch right at the center sample is because `scipy.signal.hilbert` is transforming the whole signal.

If you've done what you've said, your `vfo_channel_fm` is already a baseband signal.  All you need to do is assign that value to `baseband` in your code and proceed.

Comment: Hmm interesting, looks like i understooyyour point ... I will try tomorrow, it is to late in my time zone. Thanks for quick feedback ;)